# What is the list of permissions and intents that gmail offers in their manifest file

Tags: android, gmail, android-manifest

What intents does the gmail app listen to, and what is the full list of permissions that the gmail app uses?

Comment: Reverse engineer the app and try to get the resources using [android-apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). see if its possible to read the Manifest file. I donno what level of obfuscation they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective)'s investigation:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ
android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION
android.permission.NFC

com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL
com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL
com.google.android.gm.permission.AUTO_SEND
com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER

com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail

com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES

com.google.android.voicesearch.AUDIO_FILE_ACCESS
```

Might have missed something but that's it.